# Using the Tor api to make an anonymous proxy server

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, tor

I am making an app which makes lots of api calls to some site. The trouble I've run into is that the site has a limit on the number of api calls that can be made per minute. To get around this I was hoping to use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) in conjunction with [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to create a proxy table which uses anonymous ip addresses taken from the [tor api](https://stem.torproject.org/api.html).

So my question is, how possible is this, and what tools would you recommend for getting it done. My app is written in javascript, so solutions involving things like [node-tor](https://github.com/Ayms/node-Tor) are preferable.

Comment: I'm going to take a leap and say it's probably against the terms of service of the API provider for you to circumvent the limit. The limit is there because that's all they can afford to provide. You should ask the API provider to help you work within their limits or you should tell them why the limit is too low.

Comment: As @Bergi said -- cache the request, or set up a local server to return dummy/realistic data while you are developing.  If the data is coming back as JSON, that can even be straight text files you serve, just with the right mime type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how your proxy table will change anything: won't the distant site still received incoming requests from the same IP ? I encounter such problem with web crawlers, and I usually use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to limit the throughput of my crawler to fit with the crawled site own limits.

Comment: Using TOR sounds like an interesting option if the API you're using imposes limits by counting the number of times an IP address makes a request. Does the API also require you to provide a private key to access its services? (If so, changing the IP address the request comes from wouldn't help much, would it?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found a reasonable solution using `tor` and `curl` command line tools via Node.js.

[Download](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) the `tor` command-line tool and set it in your $PATH.

Now, we can send requests through this local `tor` proxy which will establish a "circuit" through the TOR network. Let's see our IP address using http://ifconfig.me. You can copy paste all of these things into your Node REPL:

```
var cp = require('child_process'),
    exec = cp.exec,
    spawn = cp.spawn,
    tor = spawn('tor'),
    puts = function(err,stdo,stde){ console.log(stdo) },
    child;
```

After this, you may want to build in a delay while the `tor` proxy is spawned & sets itself up.

Next, let's go through the TOR network and ask http://ifconfig.me what IP address is accessing it.

```
function sayIP(){
  child = exec('curl --proxy socks5h://localhost:9050 http://ifconfig.me',puts);
}

sayIP();
```

If you want a new IP address, restarting `tor` by turning it off and then on seems to be the most reliable method:

```
function restartTor(){
  tor.kill('SIGINT');
  tor = spawn('tor');
}

restartTor();
```

**Note:** There is another way I've seen people describe getting a new IP address (setting up a new "circuit") on the fly, but it only seems to work about 10% of the time in my tests. If you want to try it:

Find & copy `torrc.sample` to `torrc`, then change `torrc` as follows:

1. Uncomment `ControlPort 9051` (9050 is the local proxy, opening 9051 lets us control it)
2. Uncomment & set `CookieAuthentication 0`.
3. Uncomment HashedControlPassword and set to result of:

   `$ tor --hash-password "your_password"`

Then you could use a function like this to send a NEWNYM signal to your local `tor` proxy to try getting a new IP address without restarting.

```
function newIP(){
  var signal = 'echo -e "AUTHENTICATE \"your_password\"\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT" | nc -v 127.0.0.1 9051';
  child = exec(signal,puts);
}

newIP();
```